# How to export data from SSIS source to Google SpreadSheet

Tags: sql, ssis, google-sheets-api

I wanted to export data from SSIS source component to Destination (google spreadsheet) . Any help in this regard. Much appreciated.

Comment: Did you tried from your end first? If yes, let us know what errors you are getting ?

Comment: I didn't get any destination component for Google SpreedSheet. I have 3rd party api to support this destination.